# Shopify Recurring charges and one-time charges

Tags: php, api, shopify

I have Shopify application, where clients are paying with Recurring application charges: 
https://help.shopify.com/api/publishing-your-app/charging-for-your-app/recurring-application-charges. 
I would like to add one-time charges for some additional features:
https://help.shopify.com/api/publishing-your-app/charging-for-your-app/one-time-application-charge
Is it possible to use both charges type for the same client?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely do that.